# Converting DataFrame Objects to strings or Aligning DataFrame Encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, text

I am attempting to split a dataframe column of text into each separate word for analysis. For starters, I am able to do this with a small dataset from a CSV file. The working code is as follows:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('PLUSCA.csv', encoding='utf8')
#print(data)

print(data['DESCRIPTION'])
# Data type is object 

data['words'] = data['DESCRIPTION'].str.strip().str.split('[\W_]+')

# Clean Data 
dataClean = data[['SITEID', 'DESCRIPTION', 'words']].copy()
print(dataClean['words'])
```

Now the problem arises when I try to pull a MUCH larger dataset via a SQL query (which does not have the options for an `encoding='utf-8'`. I have the following:

```
SQLquery = pd.read_sql_query("""long working query""", conn) 
data = pd.DataFrame(SQLquery)

print(data.head())
print(data['LDTEXT'])

# Create word array 
print(data['LDTEXT'])
#returns correct text 
print(data['LDTEXT'].dtype)
#returns object - same as working code 
data['words'] = data['LDTEXT'].str.strip().str.split('[\W_]+')
```

I have tried several different things, including but not limited to:

```py
data['LDTEXT'] = data['LDTEXT'].astype(str)
data['words'] = data['LDTEXT'].apply(str).str.strip().str.split('[\W_]+')
data['words'] = data[u'LDTEXT'].series.str.strip().str.split('[\W_]+')

#doesnt exist but tried
data = pd.DataFrame(SQLquery, encodeing'utf-8')
```

I keep getting one of the following errors:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 172: character maps to <undefined>

SystemError: decoding with 'WINDOWS-1252' codec failed (SystemError: <built-in function charmap_decode> returned a result with an error set)

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Along with some obvious ones like:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

The only differences between the 2 datasets is the one that does not work is much text is much larger and imported from SQL instead of a CSV. Also, I tried some `astype('|S')` to handle large strings. Still no luck. I feel like this is an encoding problem. How can I check the encoding of the data and change it for SQL Imports? Does the size of the data matter? Are larger byte strings handled differently? The working dataset text is probably 1-2 sentences each, where the large set can be up to a couple paragraphs PER ROW.

OR How can I convert this properly to a string (which I'd like to avoid because I know I have a working script with `dtype object`)?

What am I missing here?

Let me know if you need more info too

**EDIT**

I added the following test

```py
for i, row in enumerate(data['LDTEXT']):
    #print("#################### NEW ROW ######################")
    #print(row)
    print(i)
    text = row.read()
    #print(text)
    try:
        print("TESTING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
        text.strip().split('[\W_]+') 
        print(text)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print(text)
        break
```

Seems Oracle creates cx_Oracle.LOB objects instead of regular python objects.

Answer (score 2):

I went through something similar, where I couldn't decode my data because I had an invalid character in my data set. After finding the row where the invalid character existed, I was able to remove it before interacting with the data.

Have you tried splitting the sentences into words on a subset of your data?

For example:

```
data.iloc[0]['LDTEXT'].str.strip().str.split('[\W_]+')
```

Can you find any rows that do work? If so, can you find any rows the specifically do not work? What does the data in the column 'LDTEXT' look like for a row that didn't work?

You can use something like the following to identify the first problematic row in your data:

```
for (i, row) in data.iterrows():
    try:
       row['LDTEXT'].str.strip().str.split('[\W_]+') 
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print(i)
        print(row['LDTEXT'])
        break
```

Comment: I am sure most rows work as it takes a while before it spits back an error. I have not been able to get to the 'first' row that does not work yet.

Comment: That does seem to further support my theory that you have an unsupported character in your data. I'll update my answer to provide an example of how you can identify the first row with an issue.

Comment: Hmmm, I got ```ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)```, I added ```data.iterrows()``` to the loop.

Comment: Hmmm, I got ```ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)```, I added ```data.items()``` to the loop. Now from the row['LDTEXT"] I am getting a key error

Comment: See the edit - test works. Seems it stops on row 163243 of 213000ish. I should be able to eliminate manually